# webkit spy tool

Tags: c#, winapi, spy++

I would like to view child component (class id, window text, pattern value etc) of a webkit created window. I have looked into almost everywhere on google but am still out of luck to find a spy tool similar to Spy++ or any methods as well windows apis to achieve this.

EDIT: I'm using C#, not C++

Answer (score 0):

those child components are not windows. Those are so called windowless controls, i.e. they're not composed of child windows but drawn directly onto the main window.

The only way to get to that information is therefore much more complicated: you have to somehow get hold of the DOM object of the web page that's shown in the window, and then find the 'control' in question by traversing the DOM.